# Move fields from one list to another

Tags: flutter

I have a list with filenames, for ex:

```
List<String> cards_string = [assets/cards/moon-rover.png, assets/cards/princess.png, assets/cards/vampire.png, assets/cards/witch.png]
```

From this list I want to make a new one, which has 2 fields: one would be a full path ( for ex: assets/cards/moon-rover.png ) and the second field would be the only filename without extension( for ex: moon rover).

So I created a class:

```
class Card {
  String url;
  String title;
  Card ({this.url, this.title});
}
```

and I defined a list of this type :

```
List<Card> cards;
```

Now I want to build the cards list, but it seems it doesn't work:

```
  for (var i=0; i<cards_string.length; i++){
    
    //Get Link
    cards[i].url = cards_string[i];
    
    // Get filname
    cards[i].title = cards_string[i].split('/').last;
    cards[i].title  = cards.title[i].split('.').first; 
  }
```

Please advise.

Later edit: This is my full code

```
class Cards {
  String url;
  String title;
  Cards ({this.url, this.title});
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  List<String> cards_string; // Table with all tiles
  List<Cards> cards;
  List<Cards> disp_cards; // = Cards(); // table to be build

    Future _initImages() async {

     // >> To get paths you need these 2 lines
     final manifestContent = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');
     final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);
     // >> To get paths you need these 2 lines

     cards_string = manifestMap.keys
         .where((String key) => key.contains('assets/cards/'))
         .where((String key) => key.contains('.png'))
         .toList();
        print(cards_string);

     cards = cards_string.map((e) => Cards(
       url:e,
       title: e.split('/').last.split('.').first,
     )).toList();


     for (var i=0; i <= cards.length; i++)
       {
         print(cards[i].title);
         print(cards[i].url);
       }
   }

   // Init state
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     _initImages();
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

       return Scaffold(
        body:
           GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount( crossAxisCount: 4),
            itemCount: cards.length,
            itemBuilder: ( context, index) => MySuperCell(context, index),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            ),
```

Comment: Did you tried ```cards[i].title = cards_string[i].split('/').last.split('.').first;``` ? You way will not work because you have to put ```cards_string[i].split('/').last;`` in temporary variable instead and then call ```.split('.').first``` on this temporary variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File paths should be Strings. Then you can do this

```
List<String> cards_string = ['assets/cards/moon-rover.png', 'assets/cards/princess.png', 'assets/cards/vampire.png', 'assets/cards/witch.png'];

class Card {
  String url;
  String title;
  Card ({this.url, this.title});
}

List<Card> cards = cards_string.map((e) => Card(
  title: e.split('/').last.split('.').first,
  url: e,
)).toList();
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, thanks! I have another issue, after I build cards I try to print results and seems that results are ok , But if I try to use cards list in Widget Build, it seems that it see it like null, for example if I try to use cards.lenght in GridView.

Comment: Make sure cards list already declared as empty list not as null. Ex: list<Card> cards = list();

Comment: And also map the string list to new variable and add that to exiting cards list using cards.addAll()